# What event handlers should I use if I want to use the values from two drop down menus and form a page?

Tags: web-applications

I need to create a suggestion page after the user clicks on two parameters, "height" and "position".
Height will be whole numbers with increments of 5 cm while the position is either "standing" or "sitting", which I have to equate to a value for the calculations later.

I would like to replicate this ---> https://www.omnicalculator.com/everyday-life/desk-height

I have tried onclick, onchange and a few others but I can't seem to figure it out.